# expo install vs npm install

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm just getting started with Expo -- but I've done RN development using the CLI. One of the first things I noticed is that I am supposed to install third party packages using `expo install <package-name>` so that we know the package is compatible.

However, I just noticed that even though Expo recommends React Navigation for navigation and routing, the first step in installing it is `npm install @react-navigation/native`. We then continue with `expo install` for installing Expo dependencies. Here's the instructions: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

I'm a bit confused here. I thought we weren't supposed to use `npm install` with Expo. What am I missing? Why are we using `npm install` for the React Navigation package and not `expo install`?

Comment: From expo docs: `The expo install command will pick a version that is compatible with your project and then use your JavaScript package manager (such as npm) to install it.`